# Largest/smallest cross-norm: A simple question about cross-norms on tensor products of Banach spaces.

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, tensor-products

This is a very simple dumb question as I’m completely new to the topic. I was reading Wikipedia’s entry on “Topological Tensor Products”, and there’s one thing I’m confused about.

Let $ A $ and $ B $ be Banach spaces, and let $ A \odot B $ denote the algebraic tensor product of $ A $ and $ B $. A norm $ \rho $ on $ A \odot B $ is said to be a *cross-norm* if
$$
\forall a \in A, ~ \forall b \in B: \quad
\rho(a \otimes b) = \| a \| \| b \| \quad \text{and} \quad
\rho'(a' \otimes b') = \| a' \| \| b' \|.
$$
The entry then says, “there is a largest cross-norm $ \pi $...” and I stopped right there.

First off, how can there be a “largest cross-norm”? If I have two cross-norms $ \rho_{1} $ and $ \rho_{2} $ on $ A \odot B $, aren’t they the same since
$$
\forall a \in A, ~ \forall b \in B: \quad
{\rho_{1}}(a \otimes b) = \| a \| \| b \| = {\rho_{2}}(a \otimes b),
$$
hence $ \rho_{1} = \rho_{2} $? What am I missing here?

Please be nice. :)

Comment: In what you have written (which is correct) you have only considered elementary tensors; what is missing is that two cross norms need not coincide on a sum $\sum_{i=1}^na_i\otimes b_i$.

Comment: Oh I get it, sorry, all the cross norms are the same on elementary tensors, an element $u$ of the algebraic tensor product $A \otimes B$ is a finite linear combination of elementary tensors.